# Azure's New Tiers (2018) - Standard vs Premium

Tags: performance, azure-sql-database

We've done what we can to index things intelligently, but we're beginning to scale up our database usage and have decided scale up (?) from Azure's S4 tier to P1. It *looks* like P1 has fewer DTUs and is going to be slower for a given amount of processing. It looks to me (and makes sense to me) like the Premium tier is primarily offered so that organizations who care have a high-availability option. I've seen some references to the premium level having a higher "IOPS per DTU", but that seems like it would break the DTU as a unit.

In short: *If I'm primarily concerned with performance and not so much with HA, is a higher-numbered (S4/S6/S7...) a better choice than a P1?* To put it another way, is one DTU always one DTU, or is a DTU in a tier harder/better/faster/stronger than one from a lower tier?

Graphic below pulled from [this page on Azure pricing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/sql-database/single/).

[image: list of tiers and DTUs]

I don't believe this is a duplicate of [this similar question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/133510/how-do-dtus-in-standard-and-premium-performance-tiers-in-sql-azure-compare), mostly because the other question appears to predate the new tier structure that is key to my question.

Comment: Hi William, thanks for asking. This might not be the best place for this question since, a similar one has quickly become useless due to the rate at which cloud offerings change. You might be best off contacting Microsoft to get more clarity / suggestions. You haven't given too many specifics, but if DTUs are your main driver I'm not sure why you're looking at P instances if the reliability (what I understand is the main draw of them) of those isn't a factor for you - sounds like you can safely upgrade to S4+. But without a lot more info, this is at best an educated guess for your needs.

Comment: Of the SE sites I know of, it seemed most appropriate here, but I could see posting it to Server Fault. It's a bit weird in either place.

Comment: Premium tiers not only offer HA options, but also is intended for IO intensive workloads because it offers SSD storage. In-memory OLTP and columnstore indexes are part of premium tiers also. Columnstore is available on Standar S3 or later).

Comment: @William-Rem I just meant SE in general, this is probably the best sub site for it if you had to choose one.